# Thread safety of a 2d slice where each thread gets its own index in first dimension

Tags: multithreading, go, slice

I am trying to ultimately end up with a 2D slice where the first dimension is equal to the number of go-routines used and the second dimension is a list of structs that each go-routine is responsible for writing to.

Type:

```
[][]*Node
```

Each go-routine will be given an index for the first dimension in the 2d slice and will only append to the list at it's index.

My first instinct was to think this was ok, but if two go-routines simultaneously need to append to their respective lists, this means I am concurrently writing to the first dimension slice.

I was thinking pointers to the second list instead of using raw lists might mitigate this concurrent write... something like:

```
workCollector := make([]*[]*Node, 5)
for i ; i < 5; i++ {
    go.Process(i)
}

func Process(threadNum int){
    localList := workCollector[threadNum]
    *localList = append(*localList, NewNode(UUID.()))
}
```

Is this enough to allow each go-routine to append to their own list or should the append happen in a mutex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your number of goroutines is constant and each goroutine is only changing its "own" data, then your original approach is thread-safe.

> My first instinct was to think this was ok, but if two go-routines simultaneously need to append to their respective lists, this means I am concurrently writing to the first dimension slice.

You may be concurrently writing to that slice but you're updating different indices in the backing array and provided you don't need to grow that slice, the backing array won't move.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it sounds like the reason thread-safety is not guaranteed for writing to a slice is because there's a possibility it can resize. Two indices in a slice can be updated concurrently by differing threads, just so long as it doesn't cause a resize of the slice. Is that right?